# Tweepy v4, Twitter API v2 and trying to tweet something with an image

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

As a learning exercise I want to make a bot that tweets an image. My current code looks like this:

```
import tweepy
import time
import subprocess
import os

# Your Twitter API keys and access tokens
consumer_key = '####'
consumer_secret = '###'
access_token = '####'
access_token_secret = '####'

# Authenticate to Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

# Initialize tweepy API
api = tweepy.API(auth)

...

    # Tweet the image
    tweet = api.update_with_media(filename=frame_file, status=f"#####")
    print("TWEET: ", tweet)

    frame_number += 1
    time.sleep(tweet_interval)
```

I have some code that generates an image and frame_file is the image. I tried using Tweepy v4 but that wasn't working, so I switched to Tweepy v3, I ran into this error:
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve', 'code': 453}]
I can't for the life of me find where this mysterious application for elevated access is anywhere online? Is there anyway to do this with Twitter API v2 thus not needing elevated access? Or is the application actually real and can be applied to.